# RTCPeerConnection.createOffer "promise" usage

Tags: javascript, webrtc, es6-promise

I am learning WebRTC recently and found a usage of "promise" here (https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/master/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel/main.js).

```
localConnection.createOffer()
    .then(offer => localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .then(() => remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(localConnection.localDescription))
    .then(() => remoteConnection.createAnswer())
    .then(answer => remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer))
    .then(() => localConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteConnection.localDescription))
    .catch(handleCreateDescriptionError);
```

localConnection and removeConnection are RTCPeerConnection objects. 
From here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection,

> createOffer:
>
> void createOffer(RTCSessionDescriptionCallback successCallback,
>   RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback failureCallback, optional
>   MediaConstraints constraints);

createOffer has 3 parameters. But why the above code does not have the parameters? where are the parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the API has been modernized with promises, and the doc is outdated.

**Before:**

```
pc.createOffer(onSuccess, onFailure, options);
```

**[After](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition):**

```
pc.createOffer(options).then(onSuccess, onFailure)
```

where `options` is optional. This should work in all WebRTC-capable browsers thanks to the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill (and also works natively in Firefox).

The ES6 `=>` arrow functions work in Firefox and Chrome 45, where you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jrpqezj4):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(failed);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);
pc2.onaddstream = e => v2.srcObject = e.stream;
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);

var start = () =>
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(v1.srcObject = stream))
  .then(() => pc1.createOffer()).then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(failed);

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
var failed = e => log(e +", line "+ e.lineNumber);
```

```html
<video id="v1" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<video id="v2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<button onclick="start()">Start!</button><div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Chrome 45 users, use the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrpqezj4), since the same code doesn't function in the stackoverflow code snippet!

Comment: Code works great, thanks. The URL for adapter.js should be replaced too with `https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js` in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

the older one( one in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection)) with three parameters, works with both firefox( including latest) and chrome, es5 compliant, the old callback based way for retriving values.( this is the one I am using my app)

the below code, is newer one, would work in latest firefox, wont work in latest chrome:

```
localConnection.createOffer()
    .then(offer => localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .then(() => remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(localConnection.localDescription))...
```

Out of curiousity, just checked what would happen when you mix, I guess you already know that `.then` == `successCallback` and `.catch` == `errorCallback`:

```
localConnection.createOffer( offer => {
        console.log('in success callback', offer); 
        if(offer) localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }, error => {
        console.log('in error callback', error);             
    })
    .then(offer => {
        console.log('in promise then', offer); 
        if(offer) localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(() => remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(localConnection.localDescription))...
```

in chrome: it would run success callback, also throw error that `undefined` has no method `then`.
in firefox: it would run success callback, also resolve with a value `undefined`.

Comment: Include [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) to use the promise version of the WebRTC API even in Chrome.